# When should the optional assembly Version, Culture, and PublicKeyToken values be specified in the web.config's compilation/assemblies collection?

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-config, httpmodule

I am creating a managed HTTP Module for IIS that will be installed in the GAC.  In order to complete the installation I need to add the assembly information to a website's web.config file.  According to [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37e2zyhb.aspx), Version, Culture, and PublicKeyToken are all optional parameters.

I believe that version must be specified when multiple versions of the same assembly may be available.  In addition, I believe that PublicKeyToken must be specified if the assembly is signed.  Is this correct?

1. Under what circumstances *should* I include one or more of these parameters, and why?
2. Under what circumstances *must* I include one or more of these parameters, and why?

**Example 1 - Fully Qualified Name**

```
<assemblies>
    <add assembly="Company.Product.Feature, Version=1.4.6.124, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
</assemblies>
```

**Example 2 - Assembly Name Only**

```
<assemblies>
    <add assembly="Company.Product.Feature"/>
</assemblies>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Always, since using GAC is more efficient in memory aspects and enables you to manage versions on your assembly making sure two assemblies can coexist.
2. When other assemblies need to use\call your assembly and they sit in, usually when your assembly needs to be known as "safe" on the machine.